# reset number order in db2sql

Tags: sql, db2

how to reset the existing data order number ? i tried `alter table tb_shk_user alter column autonum restart with 1`, it works only for new data insert the number will start from 1 the number but will duplicated with existing 1.[image]

### autonum column attribute

AUTONUM INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1) primary key

Comment: maybe create the tmp table then, copy the data to tmp table and then drop the old table and rename the tmp table to what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or this :

```
--Save data of your table into temporary table   
create table tmptable as 
(
select * from tb_shk_user 
) 
with data;

--Remove all rows into your table
delete from tb_shk_user ;

--Insert into your table all rows with renumber for autonum, be carefull all columns mus be in select except autonum
insert into tb_shk_user overriding system value
select rownumber() over(order by autonum) as newautonum, username, mobilno
from tmptable;


-- Reposition of autoincrement on max + 1
-- Example if 47896 is the max + 1 of autonum after preceding insert 
alter table tb_shk_user alter column autonum restart with 47896;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want restart for have a good series of id, then you cando it

```
--Temprary table with key autonum and new num ordered
create table tmptable as (
select autonum, rownumber() over(order by autonum) as newautonum
from tb_shk_user 
) with data;

--Update your table with new num
update tb_shk_user f1 overriding system value
set f1.autonum=
(
select f2.newautonum from tmptable f2
where f1.autonum=f2.autonum
)
where exists 
(
select * from tmptable f2
where f1.autonum=f2.autonum
);

-- Reposition of autoincrement on max + 1
-- Example if 47896 is the max + 1 of autonum after preceding update 
alter table tb_shk_user alter column autonum restart with 47896;
```